# What famous meme am I referencing with a polynomial?

Tags: mathematics, word, knowledge

What legendary meme am I referencing (twice!) with this large and strange polynomial?

> $5507x^4-302885x^3+1420806x^2-2224828x+1101400=0$

Buckleyour seatbelts, it’s kind of crazy- I sincerely hope you and your handheld calculators are up to the task, but I don't blame you if you flip your stuff. Also, don’t feel bad if you haven’t yet caught any of the five total references in this question and you’re feeling kind of lost- I’ll buy you a Caddy if you’ll cheer up. :)

Comment: I do hope y’all like my question. This isn’t a part of the puzzle, to be clear. Just feel free to let me know what you liked/didn’t, what worked/didn’t, that sort of thing. I’m very open to constructive criticism.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This polynomial references the meme

> [Loss](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/loss)

First we

> factor the polynomial:
>  `5507 (x - 50) (x - 2)^2 (x - 1)`

The

> roots are `1, 2, 2, 50` which when converted to Roman Numerals are `I II II L` which resembles the figures in the four panels of the original comic.
>  [image]

Furthermore

> the 5507, if we turn our "handheld calculators" upside down, looks like the word LOSS.

Additional hints

> "Buckleyour" refers to the comic strip author Tim Buckley. "Feeling kind of lost" references the title "Loss". The "Caddy" may reference the comic strip title "Ctrl-Alt-Del", often abbreviated CAD.

Comment: Nice! You got all five references!

Comment: Congrats on 10k! :)

Comment: kind of funny i immediately hoped it  would be this as soon as i read the question even though i missed all the references

Comment: how the heck did you figure all that out?!